# How can I ignore "-!svg-react-loader!./path/to/my.svg" when testing with Jest without bundling everything with webpack

Tags: jestjs, babel-jest

We're using svg-react-loader for some of the SVG files in our application. We're trying to setup jest to run with a babel-jest and the following **.babelrc**:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015", 
    "react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-decorators-legacy", 
    "transform-class-properties",
    "transform-object-rest-spread"
  ]
}
```

The following test fails:

```
/* global it, document */
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Comp from './Icon'

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div')
  ReactDOM.render(<Comp><div /></Comp>, div)
})
```

With error:
`Cannot find module '-!svg-react-loader!../../assets/grid.svg' from 'Icon.js'`

How could I ignore imports that start with like **import grid from '-!svg-react-loader!../../assets/grid.svg'** in jest?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The way I solved this was by adding a jest mock for any import that contains **-!svg-react-loader!** at the beginning of the module.

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
   "^-!svg-react-loader.*$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/svgImportMock.js"
}
```

Where **svgImportMock.js** is:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = 'div';
```

It's not ideal, because the file could simple not exists, but the assumption is that we see the missing module when bundling with webpack.

Comment: Did you get to a more proper solution? This will do for me too for now. but I'd like a more ideal solution

Comment: Not at this point. I'm sticking to the hack for now. Since I'm not testing anything within the SVG, it's a decent solution for me.

Comment: This requires ejecting from `create-react-app`. Is there a solution that doesn't?

Comment: I don't use create-react-app non ejected, so I'm not sure

Comment: Nice, this fixed my error: `Cannot find module '!svg-inline-loader!assets/system-icons/icon-info.svg' from 'index.js'.` 

(I just had to edit the regex slightly - `'^!svg-inline-loader.*$'`)


Thank you @VladNicula

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this by installing `jest-svg-transformer`, then adding this config:

`{
    "jest": {
        "transform": {
            "^.+\\.svg$": "jest-svg-transformer"
        }
    }
}`

Comment: what benefits does this offer compared to the solution I provided?

Comment: @VladNicula In my case all of this I have to manage is self-contained in my package.json and didn't necessitate me having to create other files.

Comment: This requires ejecting from create-react-app. Is there a solution that doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by correctly handling static assets in Jest (https://jestjs.io/docs/en/webpack#handling-static-assets):

```
// package.json
{
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js"
    }
  }
}
```

```
// __mocks__/styleMock.js

module.exports = {};
```

```
// __mocks__/fileMock.js

module.exports = 'test-file-stub';
```